# C# on OS X and Linux?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, multiplatform

I have an application coded from Visual C# Express 2008. I want to port that application to a Mac OS X ***.app** and a Linux application. How do I go about doing that? Are there any compilers available on the internet that I can download to have it parse my C# source codes and output the other OS counterparts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mono: http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

Comment: Do I need to purchase the Mono Tools for Visual Studio? And also what if I'm not using the Visual Studio but only the Visual C# Express one?

Comment: Nope, you can use SharpDevelop: http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/ to try to import your project.  It won't be perfect, so you'll have to fix whatever didn't come across. You may even run into reference issues that can't be solved, but this is the best the community has to offer.  And no, Mono is open source and free as in beer.

Comment: Those are so you can develop for Mono on Windows within Visual Studio (as far as im aware) Visual Studio will not run on OSX or Linux so you need to use SharpDevelop. However you can use the mono tool to check a Windows Developed application will run on mono. http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA

Comment: So in short, I need to have Mac OS X and Linux as well before I can develop for those platforms? I was kinda looking to develop for the 3 platforms using only Windows. Is that possible?

Comment: You can run Ubuntu inside VMWare Player on Windows.  But you can't do that with Mac OS X.  Or, I should say, you can, but it's a pretty awful experience.  You can develop on Windows with Mono and SharpDevelop, but to test you'd really want to try it on Linux and OS X.  Now, if it works in Linux, it's most likely going to be trivial to get to work in OS X since they'd be sharing the same Mono platform.

Comment: OSX runs really smoothly on VMWare Workstation 7.5, however it isn't legal to do so, because Apple sucks :)

Comment: I can't really get a Mac right now due to financial constraints. Are there any way to deploy to a Mac without having to get a mac in the first place?

Comment: Legally, no. You can get a Mac Mini for $700 which isn't too bad. http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/shop_mac/family/mac_mini?mco=MTQzMDMxODY however if I were you, I would develop for Windows and Linux, when thats all done and dusted, either find a friend with a Mac or fork out money for the Mac Mini to test with, and fix the minor issues that may be present.

Comment: Okay thanks! Back when I started with C# I had in mind that it was a quick easy step to deploy to multiple platforms. That's why I chose it over Java when I was deciding what to learn.

Comment: Lol, that's funny.  You actually thought Microsoft wanted to help people use other OSes.  Welcome to the evil world of business.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Mono project which supports all these platforms. You may need to re-work your project to deal with any Windows specific code or features specific to the MS .net implementation.